# Difference between a device subscribing to an SNS topic, and a lambda function subscribing to a topic?

Tags: amazon-web-services, push-notification, aws-lambda, apple-push-notifications, amazon-sns

Im currently trying to design a scalable push notification service, which can send notifications to 5-10 mil users in a very short time. I came across two AWS related architectures which got me confused. 
Use case: Send a notification to all the users.

1) Each device subscribes to an SNS topic, and if we want to send a push to all users, we just publish to the topics endpoint. And SNS handles the rest(sending to the million users)

2) Lambda functions are subscribed to SNS topics. We send a message to an SNS topic containing all the device tokens/batches, and then lambda calls APN/Firebase endpoints.

I fail to see in what case the second architecture would be beneficial compared to the first?

Comment: Could you please explain the second option further? Are you saying that just a single AWS Lambda function would be subscribed to the topic, and it is passed the list of 5-10 million identities to contact?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Thanks for the reply. Regarding the second option, it could be either. One option is to make batches and send those to the lambda function which then directly sends to apn/firebase. (https://blog.toppr.com/building-a-scalable-notification-delivery-service-using-aws-lambda-and-sns-f5817e2497ba)

Comment: And the other is to wrap notifictions for max SNS payload, send to SNS, a subscripted lambda function reads it which then again spawns multiple lambda functions and sends the notification. (slide 9 of: https://www.slideshare.net/AWSAktuell/sending-hundreds-of-millions-of-push-notifications-with-a-scalable-serverless-architecture-using-aws-lambda-aws-serverless-web-day) But in either case, I dont see why we cant just let all million devices subscribe to sns topic directly, instead of involving lambda functions

Comment: I agree. If it works to your with SNS, there is no need to use an AWS Lambda function. By the way, you might also be interested in learning about [AWS Pinpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pinpoint/).

Comment: I shall check it out, thank! Also, if we were to bulk send one notification to 5-10 million users, based on your experience do you think there would be any effect on overall delivery time if we use multiple lambda functions vs simply using sns?

Comment: Using a managed service is always better than writing something yourself. For example, Amazon SNS handles retries automatically. If you were to write your own 'sending' system, you'd need to manage retries yourself. Amazon SNS has a limit of 10 million subscribers. Oh, and you might not want to send millions of messages simultaneously if it involves people coming back to your website or back-end service. Such a load could cripple a system if it isn't ready for a spike in traffic.

Comment: I didn't think about that part. Thanks a lot! This helps!

Answer (score 1):

**Mobile push notification :**
    sns endpoint will created based on user device token and you will get device token from Adm,Fcm,etc like push notification platform sdk and you can trigger push notification to perticular user based sns endpoint because each device have different endpoint and it created user device token and you will have track user device token and endpoint and userId and you can able to see aws sns mobile push notification console

```
  1) you can create manually also
  2) you can create endpoint using programmatically
```

you can refer below sdks to create via code https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/mobile-push-api.html

**Lamda push notification**

You can create sns topic in sns console and you can subscribe which lambda you want deliver notification 
   basically if you want connect one lamda to another lamda you can use those case

example 1:
  you have micro service for sending otp to user and micro service deployed in different lambda and application recives sending otp request your application main lamda and now you need call otpservice lamda so you can create one sns topic and under subscription you can subscripe otp micro service lamda so main lamda will trigger otp service sns endpoint it will deliver notification micro service lamda